# Zip Archive - manually set the last modified on timestamp for the local and central headers

Tags: timestamp, zip

The customer we send our Zip Archives to requires the timestamps for all added file entries to be identical to the timestamp of the Zip Archive itself. In addition to individual entries local versus central timestamp header information. We have received this feedback:

"The timestamps in some of the local headers don’t match the timestamps in the respective central directory headers"

So, this is all new to us.
We've tried manipulating both the individual File(s) date/time stamp using .SetCreationTime and .SetLastWriteTime prior to them being added to the Zip Archive as well as using these same methods for the Zip Archive file after saving.

We then open the Zip Archive in Winzip (v23) and use the Detail Diagnostic view and see that the Zip Archive timestamp reflects our manual setting however the added files appear to be updated by the Zip Software as the Time they were added. We are using Syncfusion.Compression.Zip.

We don't see any method in Syncfusion to manually set the timestamps the Zip Software will use prior to adding the entries. We assumed it would use the operating systems timestamp but it is not. We know this because we have purposely set our Timestamp variable to one year past during testing.

So, we are hoping for some feedback on some suggestions - even if it's using some other Zip Archive software that allows us to make these setting manually so everything is in sync.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you can use rezip tool from the open-source [Zip-Ada](http://unzip-ada.sf.net/) project.

1. get / download the sources
2. build with the command `gnatmake -P zipada` (you get GNAT through apt or yum; for Windows there are pre-built binaries, or you can download GNAT from [this site](https://www.adacore.com/community))
3. you have now a binary rezip with the following options:

.

```
Usage: rezip [options] archive(s)[.zip]

Options:  -defl     : repack archive only with the Deflate
                        subformat (most compatible)
          -fast_dec : repack archive only with fast decompressing subformats
          -int      : use internal Zip-Ada algorithms only, no external call
          -touch    : set time stamps to now
          -lower    : set full file names to lower case
          -del_comm : delete comment
          -comp     : compare original and repacked archives (paranoid mode)
          -rs=n     : loop many times over a single compression approach
                        having randomization, and keep optimum when size is
                        stable after n attempts in a row
```

The command  `rezip -int -defl -touch -comp A.zip` will do the job.

Comment: I downloaded from the link you provided. Reviewed the contents and I do not see any pre-compiled binaries. How would this be added to my VS 2015 Project?

Comment: It is there https://sourceforge.net/projects/unzip-ada/files/ , under the name zipadaX-bin-win32.zip  ; pick for X the highest version number. You'll need to call rezip.exe from your program.